# Shell Script to Create a Hive Table

Tags: shell, hadoop, hbase, hiveql

I am trying to create one Hive External Table Hbase.

Below is my simple code:

```
hive -hiveconf DB_NAME=bdsma -hiveconf TABLE_NAME=RAW_BBPROCESSINGRESOURCE -f Create External table bdsma.RAW_BBPROCESSINGRESOURCE( hbase_key string,pmRohcCidSum FLOAT) ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe" STORED BY "org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler" WITH SERDEPROPERTIES '('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, \tCF:pmRohcCidSum')' TBLPROPERTIES ("COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE"="false","hbase.mapred.output.outputtable"="RAW_OPS_ODEB", "hbase.table.name"="RAW_OPS_ODEB")
```

But its showing the error below:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: TRy changing '('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, \tCF:pmRohcCidSum')' to ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, \tCF:pmRohcCidSum')

Comment: Use can use hive -e "create table sql statement" which is less confusing

Answer (score 0):

`hive -f` takes a file, so make a file containing your script, then it would be `hive -f script.sql`

If you want to write the statement on the CLI, you want `hive -e "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bdsma.RAW_BBPROCESSINGRESOURCE( ... ) ..."`. If using this way, then both `-hiveconf` can be removed because you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember 
hive -f /path/to/sql.file
your way :) Also, hive and beeline are both support this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

Find below the final script.

hive -hiveconf DB_NAME=bdsmart -hiveconf TABLE_NAME=RAW_BBPROCESSINGRESOURCE -e "Create External table RAW_BBPROCESSINGRESOURCE( hbase_key string,pmRohcCidSum FLOAT) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe' STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, \tCF:pmRohcCidSum') TBLPROPERTIES ('COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false','hbase.mapred.output.outputtable'='RAW_ERICSSON_ENODEB', 'hbase.table.name'='RAW_ERICSSON_ENODEB')"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.12.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 3.332 seconds